# How do I find and mount instance storage on my EBS backed EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-instance-store

I'm running an `m1.xlarge` EC2 instance.  According to [EC2 specs](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), it should come with `4 x 420GB instance stores`.  When I SSH into my new machine, I don't see any of these drives.  All I see are my EBS volumes:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  1.6G  6.3G  21% /
devtmpfs        7.4G   52K  7.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdf       197G   97G   91G  52% /data
/dev/xvdg        25G  3.2G   21G  14% /journal
/dev/xvdh       9.9G  151M  9.2G   2% /log
```

This is a Mongo server and I'd like to use instance storage as temporary space while backing up Mongo.  How do I locate the 420GB instance stores and mount them?  I've read the EC2 docs and I am still unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the launch wizard, you need to explicitly add the instance store volumes and specify device nodes for them:

[image]

Comment: Can I add storage to an existing instance or do I need to shut down and restart?  If I shut down, do I need to create an AMI and launch from that AMI?

Comment: Sadly, you need to create a new instance.

Comment: Interesting.  I was never given the launch wizard because I launched it through the marketplace - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00CO7AVMY/.  So can I just shut down, create an AMI, and then launch a new instance with that new AMI? Doesn't seem too bad ...but I'm surprised not enabled by default